# String literal as environment variable on VS 2012

Tags: c++, macros, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2012

I have a **VS 2005** application. A user-defined macro is defined in a property sheet to get a string literal into the built environment. For example -

```
Build_Ver, From_Build_Server=""3.1.1234""
```

In the above case, `Build_Ver` is the macro and it's value is `From_Build_Server=""3.1.1234""`. Note that the two pair double quotes are necessary in case of VS2005. If used only one pair of double quotes, macro value is considered as `3.1.1234` for `From_Build_Server`.

```
// /D "From_Build_Server=""3.1.1234"""

std::string str(From_Build_Server);

// works on VS 2005 as the value is "3.1.1234". It strips away 1 pair of "" 
// quotes.
```

When tried to replicate the same on **VS 2012**, it does something different. For the same macro, it brings the `/D "From_Build_Server=\"\"3.1.1234\"\""` to the environment.

```
std::string str(From_Build_Server);  // Fails on VS 2012 as the value is 
                                     // ""3.1.1234"". Not stripping by default.
```

If I just use 1 pair of double quotes, it works on VS 2012 but breaks on VS 2005. Is there any way to make it work on both on VS 2005 and VS 2012 ?

Comment: @WhozCraig The stringifier operator only works when used in a macro definition, i.e. inside the "body" of a `#define`.

Comment: @WhozCraig If I amn't wrong, stringizer is used for concatenation. Anyhow, I tried what you suggested. It didn't work :(

Comment: @WhozCraig Error: `'#'` not expected here